# XML file parsing issue in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

I have a xml file which I'm adding to my project locally. I have got its path and easily visible in my console when loading a view. But when I start parsing and try to get the value from the first tag it is showing nothing when I NSLog the value.
My xml file is this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QF id="AB2001" topic="Alertness" category="C&amp;M" ni_exempt="no">
<question>
    <xref>DES s4, DES s9, HC r159-161</xref>
    <text>Before you make a U-turn in the road, you should</text>
    <graphic></graphic>
    <prompt>Mark one answer</prompt>
    <voice id="AB2001-1"/>

    <explanation>
    <text>If you want to make a U-turn, slow down and ensure that the road is clear in both directions. Make sure that the road is wide enough to carry out the manoeuvre safely.</text>
    <voice id="AB2001-2"/>
</explanation>

</question>
<answers>
    <answer correct="no">
        <text>give an arm signal as well as using your indicators</text>
        <graphic></graphic>
    </answer>
    <answer correct="no">
        <text>signal so that other drivers can slow down for you</text>
        <graphic></graphic>
    </answer>
    <answer correct="yes">
        <text>look over your shoulder for a final check</text>
        <graphic></graphic>
    </answer>
    <answer correct="no">
        <text>select a higher gear than normal</text>
        <graphic></graphic>
    </answer>
</answers>
```

This is the delegate methods which I use to parse and NSLog the value to check whether it is coming or not.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([_currentElement isEqualToString:@"QF"]) {
        NSLog(@"YY%@",[attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"]);
        NSLog(@"Hi");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use below code to start parsing of xml file:

```
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathOfFile];
NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];

xmlParser.delegate = self;
[xmlParser parse];
```

Also in header file of your class conforms to NSxmlparser protocol as follows:

```
  @interface ViewController : UIViewController<NSXMLParserDelegate>
```

then Use Following method:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName

   attributes: (NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"QF"]) {
        NSLog(@"YY%@",[attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"]);
        NSLog(@"Hi");
    }

}
```

I have tried it with your file and it is working fine with my code and giving output on console as:

YYAB2001

2017-11-24 17:54:49.048539+0530 xmlParser[6718:394724] Hi

Comment: How can i  get values from tag under question? @Mangesh Murhe